# Getting error installing Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver

Tags: android-studio

it installs normally except for this weird message

```
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver installer
[SC] ControlService: ®иЁЎЄ : 1062:

> ‘«г¦Ў  ­Ґ § ЇгйҐ­ .

[SC] DeleteService: гбЇҐе
[SC] StartService ‘ЃЋ‰ б ®иЁЎЄ®© 4294967201.
Done
```

and then again says i need to install it

it may be because i have russian letters in it. if so, i don't know what to do with that.